# Finding base for a set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Given these sets of vectors:

$$
T=\{(2,1,-1),(1,0,-1),(5,1,-4)\}
$$

$$
S=\{(1,2,1),(1,1,2),(3,4,5)\}
$$

1) Find a base for the subspaces: $Sp(S)$, $Sp(T)$, $Sp(S\cup T)$

2) Describe the vectors the belong to $Sp(S)$ and to $Sp(T)$ and find a base for $Sp(S) \cap Sp(T)$

3) Verify that: $dimSp(S\cup T) + dim(Sp(S)\cap Sp(T)) = dimSp(S) + dimSp(T)$

For 1) I did:

$$
S=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 & 5 \\
\end{pmatrix}
T=\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & -1 \\
5 & 1 & -4 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Therefore:
$$
rref(S) = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
rref(T) = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$Sp(S)=[(1,0,3),(0,1,-1)],Sp(T)=[(1,0,-1),(0,1,1)]$$

$rref(Sp(S)\cap Sp(T)) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

I could not fully understand how to solve 2 and 3, may I get some help please?

So these are sufficient to represent a base for S and T respectively, right?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Based on what you found we have $v \in Sp(S) \iff v = (\alpha,\beta,3\alpha - \beta)$

To find $Sp(S) \cap Sp(T)$ think about the vectors in these $2$ subspaces and what properties they must hold in order to belong to both subspaces.

I believe you have an error in $rref(Sp(S)\cap Sp(T))$.. maybe you found $rref(S\cup T)$ instead?